# T-SQL: UPDATE perfomance in case if some column values are the same

Tags: performance, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Suppose I want to perform an UPDATE of the object stored as a row in SQL Server 2012, and some of the column values are different, but most of them are the same. Question is simple - will Sql Server perform hard disk write only of the changed columns, or it will write the entire row, uselessly rewriting existing column values with just the same? And what if the object is kept in DB spread over many tables (complex object)?

I should I rephrase my question - Is perfomance hit of doing non updating UPDATEs of some columns when updating the row worth even worrying it? 
BTW I use id column as clustered key.

Comment: It depends on many factors. Indexes, file layout, hardware resources, etc. Can't really answer your question unless you can be a lot more specific.

Comment: If you update a column with the same value then guess what - it will update the column with the same value.   Second you can only update a single table at a time.

Comment: It sounds that using DELETE/INSERT instead UPDATE will be better - but test it, to be sure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967617/sql-delete-insert-vs-update-insert check this question