# Mongo DB performance efficiency: insert vs update

Tags: mongodb, performance, insert, database

I've tried to search around and found questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967617/sql-delete-insert-vs-update-insert) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9599709/insert-vs-update) on SQL query performance, but not MongoDB.

My use case is simple, using php-mongo driver, moving documents from original collection to archive collection.

I'm concerned there would be **duplicate documents in these 2 collections with same "_id"**, so if insert() there will be "duplicate key error". Here are two ways to handle duplicate when inserting into archive collection:

1 . use update() method:

```
doc = db.original.findOne()
db.archive.update(doc['_id'], doc, { upsert: true })
```

2 . use insert() method, but in my code I need a **try-catch** block to handle Mongo DB "duplicate key error".

Apparently, using update() can avoid "duplicate key error" and I don't have to worry about duplicates. As my understanding, update() and insert() will both reference '_id' index so maybe similar speed. My question is, **is update() performance efficiency is worse than insert()**? assume I have GB or even TB archive collection.

Thank you very much.

Comment: comparing `update` performance to `insert` doesn't make sense because they are performing two different operations.

Comment: Hi I'm just wondering which strategy should I use for my use case

Comment: @keypoint It depends actually. If the update is going to increase the size of document then mongoDB may need to relocate the document. If there are frequent relocation of documents (on concurrent update) then it leads to performance issues. In such cases its better to go for insert.

Also one more point, if you need to backup a collection its better to go for mongodump command as it is very much fast

Comment: hi @SarathNair thanks for the reply. actually there would be no modify on any single document, just a duplicate insert, the new document is exactly the same as the one already in archive collection. Thank you again

Comment: In that case why iterate over whole documents in input collection? I would have used the following strategy. Read the documents from input collection sorted over _id field and archive them. I will store the _id value of last document that was archived. In the next archival process I will use the stored _id to retrieve documents like db.collection.find({_id:{$gt: storedId}}). In this case i will get documents that are not yet archived and do an insert for such documents in archival collection

Comment: I have TB data in production, sort is too expensive and blocking user requests.